# Nowadays he teaches physics because the teacher of physics has been absenting himself for a month

Tags: sentence-construction, present-continuous, present-simple

> Nowadays he teaches physics because the teacher of physics has been absenting himself for a month.

This is an error spotting question asked in my exam, I see two possible ways to correct it but don't know which one is correct.

1. Nowadays he **is teaching** physics because the teacher of physics has been absenting himself for a month.
2. Nowadays he teaches physics because the teacher of physics has been **absent** for a month.

Which is the correct way to go?

Comment: Side note: this is not an idiomatic use of **nowadays**.  Idiomatic would be **these days** (at least in AmE).

Comment: We would never say "absenting himself", which eliminates 1. automatically.

Comment: @user3169 I thought the same but found its usage here https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english-thesaurus/absent-yourself

Comment: If you check an [ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=absenting+himself&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cabsenting%20himself%3B%2Cc0), you will see the usage has decreased over time. Seems like an antiquated usage.

Comment: What is the source of your example? Any idea why it was written this way? "has been *on leave* for a month" would be a more understandable version. Also I don't think the perfect tense works since it is not a continual action.

Answer (score 1):

The second option is correct. It is redundant to use the present progressive when a limited time frame for an non-repetitive event is specified. Therefore simply using the present (teach rather than is teaching, and has been absent rather than has been absenting himself) is more concise, and more precise.

Comment: *You've been saying that all year.*  I think you need to be more specific than "when the time frame is specified".

Comment: You're right; I'm referring to events that do not stop and resume within a period of time, rather I am indicating an event that occurs once (could be continuous) in that time-frame.